# How to store refresh token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, access-token, refresh-token

I am researching for a while about storing refresh token however i am not satisfied with the information i found. I would like to know how do you store your refresh token?

Some people use to store them in a database, or cache like Redis however i think due to nature of JWT it should be stateless. But i couldn't find any other solution, i don't want to store it on device storage, because it might cause critical security leak. Could you share what your thoughts are ?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 3):

I guess it depends on what you are trying to accomplish or how the tokens are created. I found the `database` to be a great place to store `refresh tokens`. Why? Because the token is more like a password and it's easier to keep its relationship to the user when stored in the database. Also it doesn't matter what device the user is using you can always access the token from the database. For other methods you can easily loose the token when the cache or cookies are cleared. If you store them to the device a user may switch devices. However you can store an `expiring token` created from the refresh token to the device/localstorage, a cookie or some where else. Only hit the database for a refresh token when creating a new expiring token.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i think if you use database there is no need for access - refresh token mechanism, because you have additional layer which you can control. By saying that i mean, you can check database if token exists and valid, also by deleting the token from database, you are invaliding the token since we are relying on database. Keeping refresh token in database nearly same think as this. But a bit more performent because you are just making the request when access token expires. However, i got confused because jwt meant to be stateless.

Comment: Ok. I think you meant like a static token that you create for users. I always store those inside `localstorage`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage . `Refresh Tokens` are something else. https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/

Comment: no actually i dont mean access token, depends on your answer i wanted to give an example to simplify things, but i made a bit more complex i suppose. However as far as i know JWT is designed for to be stateless, to save it db or cache seems to me a bit wrong. I am actually trying to get a workaround. Some people saves the refresh token on cookies with httponly and secure flag which is protected agains XSS attack. I try to get to understand the approaches